# Own method in CreateView

Tags: python, json, django

I want to use my own method, which will return JsonResponse, but this method isn't called in this View by default. So maybe i need to rewrite another method or?

views.py:

```
class CreatePostJS(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('post_message', 'post_image')
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user',)
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'
    template_name = 'posts/post_form.html'
   
    response_data = {}
    response_data['text'] = model.post_message
    response_data['posted'] = model.posted_at
    response_data['user'] = model.user


    def create_post(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           
            return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', response_data), safe = False)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Basically if you want to execute the method on POST requests, you can override the post method with your own. It will look more or less like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    my_json_response = self.create_post(request)
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

That way there is no need to check for request.method in create_post, unless you plan to use it elsewhere.

Comment: This will not return the JSONReponse. Instead of attaching it to a variable, it needs to be returned.

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood your intentions. Have you tried just returning the jsonresponse from the post method? It should work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with generic views and want to override the default request handler, you need to overwrite the default method handler for the request method. In your case, it's the `post()` method from `CreateView` class.

I strongly recommend OOP way, so it would look like:

```
def get_request_data(self):
    return {
        'text': self.model.post_message,
        'posted': self.model.posted_at,
        'user': self.model.user
    }

def create_post(request):
    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', self.get_response_data()), safe = False)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create_post(request)
```

1. Note the `if request.method == 'POST':` is not needed, as `post()` method will only execute when POST request is being made in the current view.
2. You tried to initialize `response_data` outside a method, so as in my code you'd need to create another method for this - which I included in my example code.